# isKindOfClass returns TRUE every time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, if-statement

I have one `scrollView` named svCreateTask. In this `scrollView` I put `UITextField`, `UITextView`, `UIButtons` statically and `UIView` programmatically on button press. Now I want to remove Selected `UIView` on button press. and The view remove from `scrollView` whose tag is the same as Button tag.

And the if statement check every Time TRUE so other subview whose tag is same as my button tag also remove from `scrollView`. I want to remove only `UIView`.

Here I post My Code:

```
 NSLog(@"Enter in removeNotification method.");

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"btn Tag = %d",[btn tag]);

    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [svCreateTask subviews];

    for (int i=0; i<viewsToRemove.count; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Class == %@",[[viewsToRemove objectAtIndex:i] class]);
        if ([[viewsToRemove objectAtIndex:i]isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"In Class Check...");
            UIView *v =[viewsToRemove objectAtIndex:i];
            if (v.tag == btn.tag)
            {
                [v removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }

    }
```

and my NSLog is.

```
2014-05-13 14:49:42.769 TOPDesign[379:11303] Enter in removeNotification method.
2014-05-13 14:49:42.770 TOPDesign[379:11303] btn Tag = 1
2014-05-13 14:49:42.771 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UILabel
2014-05-13 14:49:42.772 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.773 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UITextView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.773 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.774 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UITextField
2014-05-13 14:49:42.775 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.775 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIButton
2014-05-13 14:49:42.776 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.777 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIButton
2014-05-13 14:49:42.777 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.778 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIButton
2014-05-13 14:49:42.779 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.780 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIButton
2014-05-13 14:49:42.780 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.781 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIButton
2014-05-13 14:49:42.782 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.782 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIButton
2014-05-13 14:49:42.783 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.783 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UILabel
2014-05-13 14:49:42.784 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.784 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UILabel
2014-05-13 14:49:42.785 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.786 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIImageView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.786 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.787 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIImageView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.787 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.788 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIImageView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.788 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.789 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIImageView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.789 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.790 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIImageView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.799 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.801 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.801 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.802 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.802 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.803 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIImageView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.803 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
2014-05-13 14:49:42.804 TOPDesign[379:11303] Class == UIView
2014-05-13 14:49:42.805 TOPDesign[379:11303] In Class Check...
```

My screen structure is.

```
UIView(main view) > ScrollView > TextField,TextView,Label, Buttons, UIView Etc.
```

I want to get `UIView` Which is a subview of my `scrollView`.

Comment: Well everything inherits from `UIView` so when you do `isKindOfClass:` it will always return TRUE. Can you not give the `UIView` you want to remove a tag when you create it, then just do `viewWithTag:` to get the specific `UIView` you want to remove?

Comment: @Popeye I understand something but can not understand thoroughly please explain or give simple example because i'm new in ios development.

Comment: @Popeye you want to tell me that every controll is a subclass of UIView?

Comment: I've tried to explain it in my answer with some documentation as well that will help provide a good understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to use the method `isMemberOfClass:` instead. (Check out Apple Documentation for [`isMemberOfClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isMemberOfClass%3a) method)

> `isMemberOfClass:`- Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of a given class. (required)

Whereas (Check out Apple Documentation for [`isKindOfClass:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a) method)

> `isKindOfClass:`- Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class. (required)

So basically when you do your `isKindOfClass:` check it is returning `TRUE` for any subclass of `UIView` so this includes `UIButton`, `UILabel`, etc

So change `if ([[viewsToRemove objectAtIndex:i]isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])` to `if ([[viewsToRemove objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]])`

An example of the inheritance for [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) is like `UILabel`>> `UIView` >> `UIResponder` >> `NSObject`. So when you do `isKindOfClass:[UIView class]` this will return `TRUE` for `UILabel` because `UILabel` as you can see is a subclass of `UIView` but if we did `isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]` we ignore any subclassed objects like `UILabel`, so this will return `FALSE` for `UILabel` but still return `TRUE` for `UIView`.

Another solution would be when creating your `UIVeiws` give them a tag so when it comes to removing them you can just get the specific view you want to remove using `viewWithTag:`.

Answer (score 5):

`isKindOfClass` returns true for any derived classes as well. Because all user interface related classes are derived from `UIView`, this method returns true for all objects in your case.

Use code like this, if you just want to test for a `UIView` class:

```
if ([obj class] == [UIView class]) {
}
```

This code just checks for objects of the type `UIView`.

Comment: Yes correct it is working for if ([view class] == [UIView class])

Answer (score 2):

The problem with you is that every thing in your view hierarchy is having UIView as its base class, so you are getting True every time. One possible solution to deal with this is as follows:

Give some what special tag to your UIView as if normally you are giving tag as 3, then you can just multiply its tag with 1000, now on getting True, you can calculate that if a UIView is containing three 0's, then remove it else keep it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

```
UIView *v;
for (int i=0; i<viewsToRemove.count; i++)
{
    v = [viewsToRemove objectAtIndex:i]
    if ([NSStringFromClass([v class]) isEqualToString:@"UIView"])
    {
        //Remove view
    }
}
```

Among the other answer's, I think using the `isMemberOfClass` mentioned by Popeye is the right way to do it.